# How to control microphone-speaker connection between two SIM800Ls with a GPIO terminal?

Tags: audio, differential, gsm

There is a device consisting of two [SimCom SIM800L](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf) quad-band GSM/GPRS modules and controlled by an MCU, presumably [ESP8266](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf). The idea is to let the first SIM800L call one person, the second SIM800L call another one, and then these two guys can talk to each other.

Currently schematic is as follows, and it seems to work.
[image: microphone-speaker connection between two SIM800Ls]

However I need to programmatically control whether microphone inputs are connected to speaker outputs or not. In other words, there needs to be a way for the MCU to decide when exactly parties start hearing each other and when they stop hearing each other. For this purpose I have a single free GPIO terminal.

The question is how use this GPIO to cut and later resume connection.

Comment: Can't you tell the modem to disable the speaker output through AT command? (Do you have the AT command manual and can you share it?) That GPIO you mentioned, is it from the MCU or the modem?

Comment: You could try playing with the 3 AT commands mentoned on page 36 and 37, to adjust the speaker output gain and microphone input gain to their minimum, and check if you can still ear each side, not the prettiest solution but it might work.

Comment: @Cisco25 AT commands are the last resort. Firstly, Sim800L is not always in the state where it is able to accept commands. Secondly, it is not documented how fast these commands get executed. So I would like to have more predictable, hardware-based control over voice channel.

Comment: @Cisco25 GPIO is from the MCU.

Comment: Do you need to do a bunch of configuration upon reset, if it were to control the modem reset the state using that GPIO? Might it be fast enough? I'm trying to avoid adding circuitry to the audio lines.

Comment: Oh I have a better idea! The modems have 2 channels for both microphone and speaker: main and secondary. What don't you use the AT+CHFA command to swap channels? It's basically a free switch inside the modem :) I'm pretty sure it'll be fast enough for your application.

Comment: This is the AT command manual I found:  https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's newer document than the one I have